# Passing External Vars with Ansible to a Playbook

Tags: ansible

Ansible variables passed via command line are not getting defined in the playbook.

I'm looking to pass external variables via command line to an ansible playbook.  It is not working as expected using the -e, which is to call external variables  based on the ansible documentation.

```
 ansible-playbook  /opt/playbooks/shutdown.yaml -f 10 -i /opt/inventory/hosts -e 'logPath=/my/log/path logName=shutdown.log logDir=shutdown'



---
- name: Transfer and execute a script.
  hosts: all
  remote_user: ansible
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
     - name: Transfer the script
       copy: src=/opt/files/shutdown.sh dest=/tmp/ mode=0777

     - name: Execute the script
       command: sh /tmp/shutdown.sh  logPath  logName logDir

     - name: cat log output
       command: cat logDir
       register: myoutput


     - name: get stout of execution of script
       debug: msg={{ myoutput.stdout_lines }}
```

Here is my output, I'm expecting LogPath to be defined as the variable using key:value pair

```
: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["cat", "logPath"], "delta": "0:00:00.005258", "end": "2019-02-06 13:30:03.551631", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2019-02-06 13:30:03.546373", "stderr": "cat: logPath: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["cat: logPath: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
        to retry, use: --limit @/opt/playbooks/shutdown.retry
```

Answer (score 1):

your `command` task seems wrong, you need to use curly brackets for ansible to treat the enclosed string as variable (and replace it with its value). Try this syntax:

```
 - name: Execute the script
   command: sh /tmp/shutdown.sh  {{ logPath }} {{ logName }} {{ logDir }}
```

hope it helps

Comment: think that this syntax applies to templated variables (hence the template tags). setting up default values which may then be overridden by ones supplied via the command line might even be rather stable.

Comment: your answer was about to be copied 1:1... but then he saw my comment :)

Comment: not sure what you mean by `your answer was about to be copied... but then he saw my comment :)`. in any case, i dont know how you expect ansible to treat the words `logPath  logName logDir` as variables without curly braces. you can try the code and see the results for yourself (using the `-e 'logPath=/my/log/path logName=shutdown.log logDir=shutdown'` from OP's question)

Comment: still can see that answer, which you probably can't - and have no `ansible` install at hand - merely were referring to the documentation, which assigns them directly, by name, all in snake-case.

Answer (score 0):

these should be passed in `JSON` notation, which would support passing other data-types than string:

```
-e '{"log_path":"/my/log/path","log_name":"shutdown.log","log_dir":"shutdown"}'
```

and then substitute accordingly:

```
- name: Execute the script
   command: sh /tmp/shutdown.sh log_path log_name log_dir
```

snake-case is rather the default for variable names, than camel-case.

see the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working.  I changed the code to use the JSON format, and it's not registering the key value pair.  It is using the key as the variable, rather than it's value.

Comment: `ansible-playbook  /opt/playbooks/shutdown.yaml -f 10 -i /opt/inventory/hosts -e '{"log_path":"/opt/logpath","log_name":"shutdown.log","log_dir":"shutdown"

: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["cat", "log_path"], "delta": "0:00:00.005410", "end": "2019-02-07 10:35:17.980774", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2019-02-07 10:35:17.975364", "stderr": "cat: log_path: Is a directory", "stderr_lines": ["cat: log_path: Is a directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}`

Comment: I also tried to use a external variable file, 

`cat /tmp/external_vars.yml
---
log_path: "/opt/informatica/admin/support/logs/shutdown/shutdown.log"
log_name: shutdown.log
log_dir: shutdown`

Output


`: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["cat", "log_path"], "delta": "0:00:00.005165", "end": "2019-02-07 12:13:06.092853", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2019-02-07 12:13:06.087688", "stderr": "cat: log_path: Is a directory", "stderr_lines": ["cat: log_path: Is a directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
        to retry, use: --limit @/opt/playbooks/shutdown.retry`

Comment: @SwimJim `"cat: log_path: Is a directory"` ...means you should run `cat` on a file and not a directory... or replace `cat` with `ls -la`. you should read the messages it gives you... at least it confirms that the variable is being passed & used (else it barely would complain that it is a directory). for reference: https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat & https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls ...already suspected something similar yesterday, when I've read `"cat: logPath: No such file or directory"`.

Comment: if it was passing it as a key value pair it would be listing the directory name, and not the key name.  It's having that issue because it is using the key in this snippet.

     `- name: cat log output
       command: cat  log_path
       register: myoutput`

Comment: ansible is creating a directory named "log_path" in the home directory rather than the value passed.

Comment: @SwimJim `cat` expects a file as argument, not a directory. maybe try the `{{ log_path }}` syntax, as suggested in the other answer. or try to assign them before in a `vars` configuration, before using them in commands... which might most likely be the reason. so that it first works with `vars` and then substitute these `vars` with command line arguments.

Comment: tried that and also attempted using log_path/log_dir/log_name and I'm getting errors that it is not a file or directory.  I'l try the {{ }} syntax although from the documentation that seemed like it was not for command line arguments.

Comment: @SwimJim also thought so, because it hints for template variables, but when first making command line argument `vars`, that syntax might apply. run `ansible-playbook -v -e ...` to get verbose output, to see what is even going on. without the `-v` option, it might be mere guessing.